# how to display the content when ngmodel is == " "(empty) and if ngmodel is != " " it must display other content

Tags: angularjs

my ng-model is sandtonmodel.
am using switch based on this model name. I am struggling to display some content when the model value is !=" " and it must display other content when switch is ==" "
I am doing like this.

```
       <div ng-switch="sandtonmodel">
       <div ng-switch-when="sandtonmodel != "" ">
       The Quantity in ton: {{sandtonmodel}}<br>
       Total price:{{sandtonmodel * 120}}<br>
       </div>
       <div ng-switch-when="sandtonmodel == "" ">
       The Quantity in bag: {{sandbagmodel}}<br>
       Total price:{{sandbagmodel * 120}}<br>
       </div>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the value you're switching on should be a condition, it should be a value.

You can use `ng-switch-default` to catch anything that doesn't match what you've already switched on.

Here's the documentation for [ng-switch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch).

For example:

```
<div ng-switch="sandtonmodel">
    <div ng-switch-when="">
        The Quantity in bag: {{sandbagmodel}}<br>
        Total price:{{sandbagmodel * 120}}<br>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-default>
        The Quantity in ton: {{sandtonmodel}}<br>
        Total price:{{sandtonmodel * 120}}<br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or you could use `ng-if`.

```
<div ng-if="sandtonmodel === ''">
    The Quantity in bag: {{sandbagmodel}}<br>
    Total price:{{sandbagmodel * 120}}<br>
</div>

<div ng-if="sandtonmodel !== ''"">
    The Quantity in ton: {{sandtonmodel}}<br>
    Total price:{{sandtonmodel * 120}}<br>
</div>
```

Or you could use `ng-show`.

```
<div ng-show="sandtonmodel === ''">
    The Quantity in bag: {{sandbagmodel}}<br>
    Total price:{{sandbagmodel * 120}}<br>
</div>

<div ng-show="sandtonmodel !== ''"">
    The Quantity in ton: {{sandtonmodel}}<br>
    Total price:{{sandtonmodel * 120}}<br>
</div>
```

Comment: if i use ng-show for both the condition it shows 2nd one only sir.. it displays tonn only

Comment: sir my condition is when model value is !== ""(empty) it should display 'the quantity in tonn part' and then when the model value is === empty it hide thee tonn part n it should display 'the quantity in bag part' sir..

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  If the `ng-show` example isn't working - could you explain why?  "it shows 2nd one only" - does that mean you want both to display?

Comment: see the example, when ngmodel is === ""(empty) it shoud display 'the quantity in bag' part.

Comment: when ngmodel !=="" it should display 'the quantity in tonn' part. But in your both condition it ill display 'the quantity in tonn' part only sir...

Comment: In the 1st condition (of the `ng-show` example) it uses `===` but in the 2nd condition it uses `!==` so it should only display the correct section.